# Is $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb R$ e $\beta=\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2 i\right) \in \mathbb C$. Prove that...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb R$ e $\beta=\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2 i\right) \in \mathbb C$. Prove that $\mathbb Q[\alpha] \simeq \mathbb Q[\beta]$.

$\simeq\text{(isomorphic)}$.

How will I prove it? I know I have to show that f is injection, surjective and also a homomorphism. Where to start? $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb Q[\beta]$ are not the sets of polynomials? They are constant? I'm no idea. D =

Answer (score 0):

Show that both are $\cong \mathbb R[X]/(X^3-2)$ via the "obvious" homomorphism induced by $X\mapsto \alpha$ and $X\mapsto \beta$, respectively.

Comment: Are you sure it's $\mathbb{R}[X]$? ;p